# Probability to get pair from 5-card hand poker

Tags: java, probability, poker

I need to find a probability percentage to get one pair of cards from 5-card hand by simulation.

So far I've made classes "Card" (functions: card value, suit, comparing to another card by value) and "Hand" (functions: addCard and isOnePair which returns true only if instance of hand has one pair of cards in it).

Card.java:

```
public enum CardValue { s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, J, Q, K, A }

public enum CardSuit { C, D, H, S }

private CardValue value;
private CardSuit suit;

public Card(CardValue value, CardSuit suit) {
    this.value = value;
    this.suit = suit;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if(!(obj instanceof Card)) {
        return false;
    }
    Card card = (Card)obj;
    return card.value == this.value;
}
```

Hand.java

```
private Set<Card> hand;

public Hand() {
    this.hand = new HashSet<>();
}

public void addCard(Card card) {
    this.hand.add(card);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.hand.toString();
}

private boolean isOnePair() {
    int counter = 0;
    for(Card card : hand){
        for(Card card2 : hand) {
            if(card.equals(card2)) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        counter = 0;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Edited my first post with added code.

Comment: Finding probability is a mathematical problem, for example [Probability of One pair hand in Poker 5 cards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353180/probability-of-one-pair-hand-in-poker-5-cards). I don't see how the code you posted is related to the mathematical calculation required. Can you explain how the code you posted is related to calculating probability?

Comment: I need to calculate probability by simulating poker hands.. For example give out 200k poker hands with random values and then calculate percentage of how many of them were pairs.

Comment: What do you mean by a hand with one pair?  You mean not two pair or three of a kind or four of a kind?  What about straights and flushes?  Or do you really mean "a pair or better"?

Comment: "I need to find ..." I can't find a question being asked here, this looks more like an attempt to treat stackoverflow as free code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, create a `List` deck containing all the possible `Card`s.
- Then, for each iteration of your simulation, shuffle the deck and draw the first 5 `Card`s.
- Check if there is a pair, if there is, increment a counter.
- Divide the counter by the total of iteration.

Example:

```
Random rand = new Random();

final int NUMBER_OF_VALUES = Card.CardValue.values().length;
final int NUMBER_OF_SUITS = Card.CardSuit.values().length;
final int NUMBER_OF_CARDS_IN_HAND = 5;
Card.CardValue value;
Card.CardSuit suit;
Hand hand;
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();

// Deck creation
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_VALUES; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j <  NUMBER_OF_SUITS; j++)
        deck.add(new Card(Card.CardValue.values()[i], Card.CardSuit.values()[j]));
}

int counter = 0;
final int TOTAL = 100000;

// Simulation
for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++) {
    Collections.shuffle(deck);
    hand = new Hand();
    for(int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_CARDS_IN_HAND; j++)
        hand.addCard(deck.get(j));
    if(hand.isOnePair()) counter++;
}

System.out.println("Probability: " + 100 * counter / (double)TOTAL + "%");
```

Answer (score 1):

All you care a about is that there are 52 cards and they are evenly distributed over 13 ranks.  You don't need to simulate a deck.  You just want to pick 5 random numbers between 0 and 51, with no duplicates, and then tally how many times one number's rank matches another number's rank, considering that the ranks repeat in order 4 times across the 52 choosable numbers.  If that happens just one time, you have a hand with one pair.  This takes just one loop of 5 iterations.

This code estimates the probability of exactly one pair in a 5 card hand by running 200K iterations.  It does so on my Macbook Pro almost instantaneously:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class OnePair {

    // Initialize a random number generator
    private static Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private static boolean doOne() {

        // Keep track of cards we've picked so we don't pick the same card twice
        boolean[] cards = new boolean[52];

        // Keep track of ranks we've seeen before
        boolean[] ranks = new boolean[13];

        // Keep track of how many times ranks have matched
        int count = 0;

        // For each of 5 cards...
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {

            // Pick a random card we haven't picked before
            int card;
            while (true) {
                card = random.nextInt(52);
                if (!cards[card]) {
                    cards[card] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If we've seen this rank before, increase our total matches
            if (ranks[card % 13])
                count += 1;

            // Remember that we've seen this rank
            ranks[card % 13] = true;
        }

        // Return if we saw exactly one pair, in which case count will be 1
        return count == 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long count = 200000;
        long paired = 0;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
            if (doOne())
                paired += 1;

        System.out.println((float)paired / count);

    }
}
```

Sampling of the results I get:

```
0.42265
0.42181
0.42112
0.422675
0.423895
```

I found a statistical calculation for this same problem, and the stated probability was 0.422569.